# Why is my year from strftime() method not outputting what I expect

Tags: c++, c++11, strftime

I am trying to convert a date to a time in a format that I want and it's giving an unexpected output.

```
struct tm dateTime = {0};
char buffer[80]= {0};

dateTime.tm_year = 2014;

dateTime.tm_mon = 4;
dateTime.tm_mday =17;

strftime(buffer, _countof(buffer), "%d-%b-%Y", &dateTime);
```

- I expect to see `17-May-2014` but instead I see `17-May-3914`.
- I feel like I might be missing something but I can't figure out what.  Any ideas?

Comment: use dateTime.tm_year = 2014-1900; 1900 is calibration for tm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tm_year` holds the number of years since 1900.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dateTime.tm_year = 2014-1900;` The 1900 value is calibration for `tm` - it stores number of years after 1900.